# Is it more optimized to use local function or global function?

Tags: delphi

I want to know if it's more optimized to use a **local function** (in the exemple below `_drawBitmap`) who require only **3 parameters** and **can't be inlined** because the function access some owner procedure variables, or to use a **global function that can be inlined** (but does it will be really inlined?) and that will require **5 parameters**.

also don't know if it's important but this code is mostly for android/ios compilation

Code With local function :

```
procedure TMyObject.onPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);

  function _drawBitmap(const aBitmap: {$IFDEF _USE_TEXTURE}TTexture{$ELSE}Tbitmap{$ENDIF}; const aTopLeft: TpointF; Const aOpacity: Single): boolean;
  var aDestRect: TrectF;
  begin
    Result := False;
    if aBitmap <> nil then begin

      //calculate aDestRect
      aDestRect := canvas.AlignToPixel(
                     TRectF.Create(
                        aTopLeft,
                        aBitmap.Width/ScreenScale,
                        aBitmap.Height/ScreenScale));

      //if the aBitmap is visible
      if ARect.IntersectsWith(aDestRect) then begin

        Result := True;

        {$IFDEF _USE_TEXTURE}
        TCustomCanvasGpu(Canvas).DrawTexture(aDestRect, // ATexRect
                                             TRectF.Create(0,
                                                           0,
                                                           aBitmap.Width,
                                                           aBitmap.Height), // ARect
                                             ALPrepareColor(TCustomCanvasGpu.ModulateColor, aOpacity * AbsoluteOpacity), // https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15432
                                             aBitmap);
        {$ELSE}
        Canvas.DrawBitmap(aBitmap, // ABitmap
                          TRectF.Create(0,
                                        0,
                                        aBitmap.Width,
                                        aBitmap.Height), // SrcRect
                          aDestRect, // DstRect
                          aOpacity * AbsoluteOpacity, // AOpacity
                          samevalue(aDestRect.Width, aBitmap.Width, Tepsilon.Position) and
                          samevalue(aDestRect.height, aBitmap.height, Tepsilon.Position)); // HighSpeed - set interpolation to none
        {$ENDIF};

      end;

    end;
  end;

begin

  _drawBitmap(aBitmap, aPos, 1);

end;
```

ASM :

```
MyObject.pas.2632: _drawBitmap(fBtnFilterBitmap, // aBitmap
00B97511 55               push ebp
00B97512 680000803F       push $3f800000
00B97517 8B45F8           mov eax,[ebp-$08]
00B9751A 8D90C4050000     lea edx,[eax+$000005c4]
00B97520 8B45F8           mov eax,[ebp-$08]
00B97523 8B80A8040000     mov eax,[eax+$000004a8]
00B97529 E882FDFFFF       call _drawBitmap
00B9752E 59               pop ecx


MyObject.pas.2562: begin
00B972B0 55               push ebp
00B972B1 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
00B972B3 83C4A0           add esp,-$60
00B972B6 53               push ebx
00B972B7 56               push esi
00B972B8 57               push edi
00B972B9 8955FC           mov [ebp-$04],edx
00B972BC 8BF0             mov esi,eax


MyObject.pas.2563: Result := False;
00B972BE 33DB             xor ebx,ebx
MyObject.pas.2564: if aBitmap <> nil then begin
00B972C0 85F6             test esi,esi
00B972C2 0F84B4010000     jz $00b9747c
MyObject.pas.2567: aDestRect := canvas.AlignToPixel(
00B972C8 8B450C           mov eax,[ebp+$0c]
00B972CB 8B78FC           mov edi,[eax-$04]
00B972CE 8BC6             mov eax,esi
00B972D0 E88F559BFF       call TBitmap.GetWidth
...
```

and with global function :

```
function drawBitmap(const Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF; const aBitmap: {$IFDEF _USE_TEXTURE}TTexture{$ELSE}Tbitmap{$ENDIF}; const aTopLeft: TpointF; Const aOpacity: Single): boolean; inline;
var aDestRect: TrectF;
begin
  Result := False;
  if aBitmap <> nil then begin

    //calculate aDestRect
    aDestRect := canvas.AlignToPixel(
                   TRectF.Create(
                      aTopLeft,
                      aBitmap.Width/ScreenScale,
                      aBitmap.Height/ScreenScale));

    //if the aBitmap is visible
    if ARect.IntersectsWith(aDestRect) then begin

      Result := True;

      {$IFDEF _USE_TEXTURE}
      TCustomCanvasGpu(Canvas).DrawTexture(aDestRect, // ATexRect
                                           TRectF.Create(0,
                                                         0,
                                                         aBitmap.Width,
                                                         aBitmap.Height), // ARect
                                           ALPrepareColor(TCustomCanvasGpu.ModulateColor, aOpacity * AbsoluteOpacity), // https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15432
                                           aBitmap);
      {$ELSE}
      Canvas.DrawBitmap(aBitmap, // ABitmap
                        TRectF.Create(0,
                                      0,
                                      aBitmap.Width,
                                      aBitmap.Height), // SrcRect
                        aDestRect, // DstRect
                        aOpacity * AbsoluteOpacity, // AOpacity
                        samevalue(aDestRect.Width, aBitmap.Width, Tepsilon.Position) and
                        samevalue(aDestRect.height, aBitmap.height, Tepsilon.Position)); // HighSpeed - set interpolation to none
      {$ENDIF};

    end;

  end;
end;

procedure TMyObject.onPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas; const ARect: TRectF);
begin

  drawBitmap(aBitmap, aPos, 1);

end;
```

ASM:

```
MyObject.pas.2636: drawBitmap(Canvas, aRect, fBtnFilterBitmap, // aBitmap
00B98F6D 8BFB             mov edi,ebx
00B98F6F 8B83A8040000     mov eax,[ebx+$000004a8]
00B98F75 8945F0           mov [ebp-$10],eax
00B98F78 8D83C4050000     lea eax,[ebx+$000005c4]
00B98F7E 8945EC           mov [ebp-$14],eax
00B98F81 C645EB00         mov byte ptr [ebp-$15],$00
00B98F85 8B75F0           mov esi,[ebp-$10]
00B98F88 85F6             test esi,esi
00B98F8A 0F840A020000     jz $00b9919a
00B98F90 8BC6             mov eax,esi
00B98F92 E8CD389BFF       call TBitmap.GetWidth
...
```

Comment: Look for "Do not use nested routines" [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20020406005808/http://www.optimalcode.com:80/general.htm) for an ancient optimization guide.

Comment: Quote: "Nested routines (routines within other routines; also known as "local procedures") require some special stack manipulation so that the variables of the outer routine can be seen by the inner routine. This results in a good bit of overhead. Instead of nesting, move the procedure to the unit scoping level and pass the necessary variables - if necessary by reference (use the var keyword) - or make the variable global at the unit scope."

Comment: @Uli I'm calling you out on that blanket statement. My experience says otherwise. You can't be serious about using global variables? How can you endorse blanket advice without profiling?

Comment: @UliGerhardt: thank for the link but unfortunatly it's blocked by the law in russia and i can't access it :(

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't write that guide and didn't mean the link to be a "blanket statement". The part about global variables is not the point of the advice - it's about nested vs global routines. Also I don't know if the advice is still valid - that's why this is just a comment and not an answer.

Comment: That's fine, I really wanted to register some caution so that nobody takes that advice too uncritically

Comment: Including x86 asm is kinda pointless. Unless you are a performance geek, you won't be able to infer much from it, and you stated yourself that the important target is ARM!

Answer (score 6):

Here, calling the function will be instantly, in respect to using the VCL `TCanvas`. So it is clearly premature optimization, and there is no performance difference in practice between the two. The global function may be more difficult to maintain (unless it is some code which can be actually be reused somewhere else in the unit). Anyway, even a global function is not a good idea: if you have some specific reusable process, define a `class` instead: it will be cleaner and easier to debug/extend/test.

Only for very small functions, which do not call any other functions, inlining may give some performance benefits. For instance:

```
function Add(n1,n2: integer): integer; inline;
begin
  result := n1 + n2;
end;
```

But in your case, it won't make any sense.

And, as you stated, it is up to the compiler to actually inline the asm, or not. If it states that inlining won't make any benefit (it may even be slower than a sub-function), it won't inline the function.

For completeness, at low asssembly level, when you call a local function within another function, access to the variables in the scope is done adding the caller "stack frame" pointer as an additional parameter.

In pseudo code, it is like that:

```
function _drawBitmap(const stackframe: TLocalStackRecord; const aBitmap: {$IFDEF _USE_TEXTURE}TTexture{$ELSE}Tbitmap{$ENDIF}; const aTopLeft: TpointF; Const aOpacity: Single): boolean;
  var aDestRect: TrectF;
  begin
    Result := False;
    if aBitmap <> nil then begin

      //calculate aDestRect
      aDestRect := stackframe.canvas.AlignToPixel(
                     TRectF.Create(
                        aTopLeft,
                        aBitmap.Width/ScreenScale,
                        aBitmap.Height/ScreenScale));
  ...
```

Try to avoid premature optimization:

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying
>   about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these
>   attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when
>   debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that
>   critical 3%.
>   *Variant in Knuth, "Structured Programming with Goto Statements". Computing Surveys 6:4 (December 1974), pp. 261–301, §1.*

To avoid wasting your time (and money), use a profiler - e.g. [Eric's Sampling Profiler](https://www.delphitools.info/samplingprofiler/) - to find out which part of your code will actually need to be optimized.

Make it right, then make it fast. And make it always readeable and maintainable.

Comment: It's FMX code rather than VCL although the conclusions are just the same

Comment: thanks arnaud! i update a little my question and add the asm of the 2 variants, as you can see, it's seam that the global inlined function use much less code than the local functions. I 100% agree with your advice about worrying for the speed of noncritical parts of their programs ...

Comment: Difficult to make sense of that comment. Do you want the code to run fast on iOS/Android, or do you want to minimise the size of the compiled x86 code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: on ios/android of course but it's little complicated for me to retrieve the ARM compiled code (debuger is bugy right now).

Comment: So what are you hoping learn from looking at x86 code? It seems to me that you are making a lot of mistakes here. Looking at the wrong code. Looking at code rather than timing it. Trying to optimise code that isn't a bottleneck.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to be sure is to profile the performance of the two variants.

That said, looking at the code, my instincts tell me that you won't be able to measure any significant difference between the two variants. The performance will be determined by the system functions that are called, rather than your high level code. But, that's just an educated guess. Compare the two and measure.

As far as your use of inline goes, I am somewhat sceptical of it here. That's quite a large function and inlining tends to be most effective with short leaf functions. Again, I doubt that inlining here will change anything but my instincts say that, if anything, inlining here is more likely to hinder performance than help.

The other thing to stress is that you should concentrate on optimising bottlenecks first. Have you checked that this function is a bottleneck? If it is not, then any optimisation effort is wasted.